# Android Studio: How to clear "n" number of stacks

Tags: android, android-fragments, stack, fragment

I couldn't really find anything online, every thread i've seen on SO was about how to clear all the stack and entire stack history. But I need to specifically clear the last 6 stacks in my program.

Is there any way to clear the last *n* number of stacks in an activity?

Or what I need to do is clear all the back stack to go to my last previous fragment.

Scenario: One screen has four fragments at the bottom the user can select.

Fragment A
Fragment B
Fragment C
Fragment D

An activity is called from Fragment B in which 5 more activities are called.

I need to clear all 6 of those and go back to Fragment B. But right now if I cleared all the stack it'll go back to Fragment A, which I don't want.

So now my question is how would I go back to Fragment B upon clearing the back stack?

Comment: "But right now if I cleared all the stack it'll go back to Fragment A" -- why? that activity should be in the same state where you left it, assuming your process has not been terminated somewhere along the line. If Fragment B was showing, Fragment B should still be showing.

Comment: Because the MainActivity that calls it by default calls Fragment A, but if I go back to the stack it'll be saved at Fragment B. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult() and can expect some sort of indication from the top activity to call finish() in protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method.